# Почему console.log() влияет на значение переменной?

Tags: javascript

Для пролистывания задач у меня есть функция изменяющия номер текущей задачи:

```
  prevIssue () {
    var index = this.state.currentIssueIndex;
    console.log(index === 0 ? index : index--);
    var newIndex = index === 0 ? index : index--;
    this.setState({
      currentIssueIndex: newIndex
    });
  }
```

В приведено виде она работает.
Но если я уберу `console.log()` то значение индекса меняется не будет.
(не будет уменьшатся на единицу)

Почему это происходит, как правильно реализовать функцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Почему

Потому что эта запись

```
console.log(index === 0 ? index : index--);
```

эквивалентна такой

```
let res;
if (index === 0)
  res = index;
else
  res  = index;
  index--;
}
console.log(res);
```

#### Что делать

Заменить код таким

```
console.log(index);
if (index !== 0)
  index--;
```

тогда строку `console.log(index);` можно будет убирать при ненадобности.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что при `index`, отличном от нуля, вычисляется второй операнд выражения

```
...index === 0 ? index : index--
```

Используйте `if`

```
  prevIssue () {
    var index = this.state.currentIssueIndex;
    if (index !== 0)
      index--;
    var newIndex = index === 0 ? index : index--;
    this.setState({
      currentIssueIndex: newIndex
    });
  }
```

Comment: Понятно, в console.log  срабатывает декремент

Comment: не забывайте ставить галочки